# Can 'one' as a pronoun be replaced with he/she or anyother pronoun later on in the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I found the following information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)). I want to know whether its usage is grammatically correct. (from academic perspective)

[image: one (pronoun) wikipedia]

Comment: This is a specifically American usage that sounds wrong to English ears (at least mine). I don't know what speakers of AmE think about it.

Comment: Pronouns can always be changed in the middle of a sentence—although it's more common to change a pronoun to its actual referent. So long as they still refer to the same thing, it's a matter of style, not grammar.